# SLDS VF Page Cancel button not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, slds

When I click on Cancel button that is part of the VF SLDS page, I get an error specifying that Last Name for contact is needed.How can I bypass the standard field validation? 
 Here is my button:

```
<li class="slds-button-group-item">
        <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" value="Cancel" action="{!cancelNewContact}" immediate="true" />
</li>
```

This is the method I am calling from my custom controller:

```
public pageReference cancelNewContact(){
    pageReference cancelNewContact = donorSearchGMSURL;
   cancelNewContact.setRedirect(true);
return cancelNewContact;
}
```

Here is my SLDS VF Last Name field.

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_horizontal">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">
      <abbr class="slds-required" title="required">* </abbr>Last Name</label>
   <div class="slds-form-element__control">                                                                            
       <apex:inputField value="{! con.LastName }"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could I be seeing the problem because <apex:inputField value="{! con.LastName }"/> is bound to an Contact Object record? If I unbind it, it works. The funny part is that I have another standard required lookup field, but yet upon cancel, that button is not being flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Place the cancel button within an action region:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" ... />
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Do not use `immediate="true"`, as this will cause your code to not run (this mode only allows reRendering without meeting Visualforce validation for required fields).

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I did follow your instructions, added the tags and removed immediate, but still the same result. The out of the box validation for Contact's last name is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use:

```
<apex:commandButton value="cancel" onclick="reload();" />
```

It doesnt need any apex method, you just need to refresh tab to cancel form. `reload()` does that.

Comment: I need the apex method, because I am trying to send the user back to an earlier VF page, with assigned params in the URL.

Comment: I also just for the test of it, I added onclick="reload()", and removed the call for the class, and the field validation is still being invoked.